# Date Validotor gives Exception and does not work like Other Filters

Tags: zend-framework2

I am using the 4 Stage Registration Page in Zend Framework.

```
I am using Filter Class. All validations works fine and display error in their approriate place(near the element), If there is any Issue.
```

But i have problem with "Date" element. it does not gives error like other validotors and it breaks the page in case of invalid date format.

I am using Like

```
 $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'user_profile_dob',
             'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Date',
             'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Birth Date',


            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'user_profile_dob',
                'readonly' => true,
                'placeholder' => date("m/d/y"),//set selecarray()ted to '1'
                'min'  => '1800-01-01',
                'max'  => '2010-01-01',
            )            

        ));
```

What i am missing

How to use Date element so that it display error like others.Right now it is showing error with page break

```
An error occurred
An error occurred during execution; please try again later.
Additional information:
Zend\Filter\Exception\InvalidArgumentException

File:

    C:\wamp\www\1625\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Filter\DateTimeFormatter.php:60

Message:

    Invalid date string provided
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Zend\Form\Element\Date` element by default has the `DateTimeFormatter` filter attached. The `DateTimeFormatter` filter throws an exception if the date format is incorrect. You can avoid this exception if you either remove the `DateTimeFormatter` from the input filter for your form, or use the `Zend\Form\Element\Text` element instead.